Grep for multiple strings on the same line
How can I print the output on the shell to show me only the lines containing the following 2 strings and I dont want to see any other lines.
Changing
66824113

The lines on the log are:
25 Jul 2024 08:25:41,252 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO : Changing TOTAL_QUANTITY to 5080000.00000000 trade_leg [66824113][1][]

25 Jul 2024 08:25:41,303 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO : Changing ACCRUED_INTEREST to 91763.85 trade_leg [66824113][1][]

Now I only want to see those lines which contains the strings "Changing" and "66824113".
I tried many commands but nothing seems to work as it always prints other lines alongwith the lines I want, but I dont want to see other lines.

grep -E 'Changing.*[66824113]' 'filename'

grep -P '(?=.?Changing) (?=.?66824113)' 'filename'

cat 'filename' | awk '/Changing/ && /[66824113]/


Above 3 didnt serve my purpose.

If either string could be first, use grep Changing filename | grep 66824113

If Changing always comes before 66824113, then your first attempt was close, except you should not have the square brackets around the number.  Square brackets have special meaning in grep, so your command was actually looking for any of the digits 6, 8, 2, 4, 1, or 3.

Don't put the digits inside a bracket expression. 68 means "the digit 6 followed by the digit 8" while what you were doing, [68] means "the digit 6 or the digit 8".
grep 'Changing.*66824113' file

finds Changing followed by 66824113 while:
awk '/Changing/ && /66824113/' file

finds Changing and 66824113 in any order.
68 means "the digit 6 followed by the digit 8" while what you were doing, [68] means "the digit 6 or the digit 8".

Amazing, many thanks Ed.

You're welcome, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.
